# Iterating over a Python 2D list to find the value

Tags: python, list, loops, iteration

I am trying to iterate over a Python 2D list. As the algorithm iterates over the list, **it will add the key to a new list until a new value is detected**. An operation is then applied to the list and then the list is emptied so that it can be used again as follows:

```
original_list = [('4', 'a'), ('3', 'a'), ('2', 'a'), ('1', 'b'), ('6', 'b')]
```

When the `original_list` is read by the algorithm it should evaluate the second value of each object and decipher if it is different from the previous value; if not, add it to a temporary list.

Here is the psedo code

```
temp_list = []
new_value = original_list[0][1] #find the first value

for key, value in original_list:
    if value != new_value:
        temp_list.append(new_value)
```

Should output

```
temp_list = ['4', '3', '2']
```

Comment: So whats your question? also it would be better if you add your expected output to question!

Comment: [This answer explains OrderedDicts for you](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9001529/4374739) if you'd prefer to use a sortable dictionary system.

Comment: Just a note: Defining `new_value` as `"a"` will cause the first iteration to do something with `temp_list`, which would be empty. I suppose that's undesirable. Perhaps adding to the comparison: `if value != new_value and temp_list:`, to ensure you won't do operations with an empty list?

Comment: What seems to be the problem?

Comment: You can also use a sorted dict-like type. There are many options on PyPI and elsewhere (blist, SortedCollections, sortedcontainers, rbtree, bintrees, skiplistdict...) that maintain sorted order as you mutate them (at the cost of some operations taking logarithmic rather than linear time).

Comment: The boltons python library has a great `OrderedMultiDict`. Among other things, the "ordered" part of the dict facilitates sorting, and the "multi" part of the dict let's you invert keys and values easily.

Comment: Meanwhile, why are you comparing and storing the values if your desired output is the duplicate _keys_? Is that your whole problem? If so, the fix is trivial...

Comment: @S_A: when editing, please note that inline code spans (`like this`) [shouldn't be used for highlighting](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254990), only for code in sentences. Also, please try and improve the post as much as possible when editing to save the reviewers time. Thanks!

Comment: @Qantas94- Okk, I understand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
temp_list = []
prev_value = original_list[0][1]

for key, value in original_list:
    if value == prev_value:
        temp_list.append(key)
    else:
        do_something(temp_list)
        print temp_list
        temp_list = [key]
    prev_value = value

do_something(temp_list)
print temp_list

# prints ['4', '3', '2']
# prints ['1', '6']
```

Comment: From the OP's question: "An operation is then applied to the list" ... since I do not know what operation that is, I used a placeholder => `do_something()`

Answer (score 1):

Not entirely sure what you are asking, but I think [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) could help:

```
>>> from itertools import groupby
>>> original_list = [('4', 'a'), ('3', 'a'), ('2', 'a'), ('1', 'b'), ('6', 'b')]
>>> [(zip(*group)[0], k) for k, group in groupby(original_list, key=lambda x: x[1])]
[(('4', '3', '2'), 'a'), (('1', '6'), 'b')]
```

What this does: It groups the items in the list by their value with `key=lambda x: x[1]` and gets tuples of keys corresponding to one value with `(zip(*group)[0], k)`.

Answer (score 1):

In case your "keys" do not repeat themselves, you could just use a [`defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) to "sort" the values based on keys, then extract what you need

```
from collections import defaultdict
ddict = defaultdict(list)
for v1, v2 in original_list:
    ddict[v2].append(v1)
```

`ddict` values are now all `temp_list`:

```
>>> ddict["a"]
['4', '3', '2']
```